# How to close the browser window in pug/Jade

Tags: javascript, pug

we are implementing OAUTH authenticataion for login. After click on the link from my application it is redirecting to the browser where the login page is opening. The page is configured using Jade/pug and implemented using form validation and routing mechanism using express js.

But while trying to close the browser window with the close button, getting the below error saying:

`Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it`

### ***login.jade***

```
 form(name="myForm", action="/login",method="POST",novalidate)
                        divForm
                            divw1
                                .group
                                    input(type='number', required='', name="userid",autocomplete="off", data-required-msg='Username is required')
                                    label Enter User ID
                            divw1
                                .group
                                    input(type='password', required='', name="password")
                                    label Enter Password
                        divButtons
                             input(type="button",value="CANCEL",onClick='onBtnClk()',ID="cancel")
     input(type="submit",value="LOGIN",ID="login")
```

### login.js

```
   var express = require('express');
   var router = express.Router();

    router.post('/', '', function(req, res, next) {
        if (req.body.userid === '' && req.body.password === '') {
            // Looks like the user not provided credentials, let's show the ui again...

            res.render('login', {
              error: 'User ID and Password are mandatory'
            });
            return;
          }

    });
```

### layout.jade

```
function onBtnClk(){
  window.top.close(); //window not closing(Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not about Pug,
it's about the JavaScript API.
The API only allows your script to close windows that were opened by a script,
see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_close.asp).

So as long as your window is not opened by a script you will not be able to close it, meaning you should rather tell the user that the login was successful and they can close the window

Comment: thanks @Lennart, but the problem is , the user is trying to click on the submit button with out entering the proper data. And we are showing the error messages for each form field. After he try to click on cancel button and the window is not closing.

Comment: Exactly, because the JavaScript API simply does not allow this close button.